# перегрузка оператор() через оператор[][] на c++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

нужно так чтобы `data[5][5]` код выводил как `data(5,5)` и как результат выдавал произведение `i` на `j`, т.е. `5*5=25`.
Желательно, чтобы была имплементация классов
header file примерно такой:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
class Data {
 public:
 mineData();// это функция, которая должна включать перегрузку
 
 int data()( int, int );
 private:
 int data[5][5];
};
#endif
```

Comment: звучит как ТЗ, но что-то не видно суммы...

Comment: покажите класс, который вы сделали.. и покажем как сделать

Comment: Тут нужно два класса с перегуженными операторами индекса.

Comment: добавил уточнение

Comment: ваш класс полная чушь. не компилируется.

Comment: так помогите или напишите так, как вы бы написали, учитывая то описания, чтоя добавил, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    struct Impl
    {
        int a;
        auto operator[](int b)
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    };
public:
    auto operator[](int a)
    {
        return Impl{a};
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test data;

    std::cout << data[7][6] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Запустить код](https://ideone.com/cUYsv2)